# Ubuntu 22.10 audio lag when enabled lock screen

Tags: sound, 22.10

Ubuntu 22.10
Motherboard MSI z97 u3-plus
`sudo lshw -C sound`

```
description: Audio device
       product: 9 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1b
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
       logical name: card0
       logical name: /dev/snd/controlC0
       logical name: /dev/snd/hwC0D0
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D0c
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D2c
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:38 memory:f7310000-f7313fff
```

Problem: When I listen to music (on YouTube, Spotify, or other platforms) and the screen goes into lock mode, the audio starts to skip every 5 seconds. This happens with Bluetooth headphones, jack headphones, or USB headphones.